# boleto php - como verificar se o boleto gerado pelo meu sistema foi pago

Tags: php, api, boleto

Meu sistema está gerando boleto para serem pagos no Banco do Brasil. Como faço pra saber se aquele boleto foi pago?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara, isso tem uma miríade de respostas.

Geralmente os bancos emitem um arquivo de retorno de boleto, geralmente .ret e usei onde trabalho um plugin de classes que leem esses tipos de arquivos.

https://github.com/manoelcampos/Retorno-BoletoPHP

Outro caso pelo qual passei é que o arquivo dado pelo banco a empresa que eu estava fazendo o sistema não cabia nesse plugin, então tive que criar um parser pro arquivo de texto custom, criei baseado nesse plugin.

E no último caso, é deixar o cara fazer baixa manual desses boletos. Eu sei que não é exatamente profundamente esclarecedor, mas foram as soluções que achei.

Comment: Obrigado. Mas até onde pude ler, pra ter esses arquivos de retorno eu preciso (o site neste caso) ter contrato com o banco, só assim eles me enviariam o arquivo e não tenho contrato com o banco. tem como ter este arquivo sem ter contrato ou ter esse retorno de outra forma ?

Comment: @HectorCardoso não.