# Notificação de boleto bancario

Tags: php

Olá,

Tenho um script que gera boleto bancário e funciona perfeitamente, porém quero ver como faço para que o meu sistema saiba se esse boleto foi pago, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Já ouviu falar em CNAB? https://blog.vindi.com.br/o-que-e-o-cnab-e-para-que-ele-serve/ Vários bancos disponibilizam o manual para poder desenvolver o layout de arquivo de remessa

Comment: Duplicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64028/boleto-php-como-verificar-se-o-boleto-gerado-pelo-meu-sistema-foi-pago

Comment: Gerei esse arquivosantander-cnab-240, como poderia utilizar com o PHP?

Comment: vi ali que ele cria um arquivo .ret. Como eu poderia gerar esse arquivo com o PHP?

Comment: Olá Wagner. Tudo bem? Você conseguiu resolver o seu problema? Pergunto porque estou querendo aplicar a mesma solução, porém não estou encontrando como faço isso. Obrigado.